# I want to beable to record the same audio input with multiple applications

Tags: sound, sharing, input

As my title says.  I would like to beable to record the same audio input from my sound card to multiple applications.

I have been told it can be done with a modification to asoundrc but I don't know where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Daryll

Comment: IMHO the best place to start is with Ubuntu studio and jack ;) Both ubuntu studio and KXStudio - http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/ have graphical tools for what you want.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need it all to be done from the command line as there will be no gui.  I am using Ubuntu server.

Comment: Not sure why you are using a server for this project, but OK. I would still use Ubuntu studio and kxstudio. If you must, you can configure jack with a script - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/JACK_Audio_Connection_Kit#A_shell-based_example_setup

Comment: Because I don't need a traditional gui.  It is for automated recording

Comment: OK, so, jack will do what you want and the link from the arch wiki will show you how to configure jack from the command line. If you have trouble either use the graphical tools (much easier if you are new to jack) or start posting your hardware, desired configuration, and what script / configuration you used for jack. If you are not going to use ubuntu studio or KXStudio, see http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/system_configuration for all the likely system modifications you may need to consider as well. (KXStudio and Ubuntu studio have these configurations by default).